# TensorFlow TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not iterable / TypeError: 'CacheDataset' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm following the [TensorFlow starter guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager). It specifically said to enable eager execution on the sample project for iris (flower) classification.

> Import the required Python modules, including TensorFlow, and enable eager execution for this program. Eager execution makes TensorFlow evaluate operations immediately, returning concrete values instead of creating a computational graph that is executed later. If you are used to a REPL or the python interactive console, you'll feel at home.

So I followed the instructions to enable eager execution, and continued the instructions. However, when I reached the section discussing how the dataset will be prepared into a tensor flow dataset, I encountered an error.

#### Cell code

```
train_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(train_dataset_fp)
train_dataset = train_dataset.skip(1)             # skip the first header row
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_csv)      # parse each row
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)  # randomize
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32)

# View a single example entry from a batch
features, label = iter(train_dataset).next()
print("example features:", features[0])
print("example label:", label[0])
```

#### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-61bfe99af85b> in <module>()

      7 
      8 # View a single example entry from a batch
----> 9 features, label = iter(train_dataset).next()
     10 print("example features:", features[0])
     11 print("example label:", label[0])

TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not iterable
```

I just want to continue following the examples. What can I do to transform the `BatchDataset` object into something iterable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I actually failed to do certain steps in the project that caused this problem.

#### Upgrade TensorFlow from 1.7 to 1.8:

`!pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

#### Checking if your TensorFlow is updated

This code cell:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tf.enable_eager_execution()

print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.VERSION))
print("Eager execution: {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))
```

Should return the following output:

```
TensorFlow version: 1.8.0
Eager execution: True
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642569/batchdataset-not-subscriptable-when-trying-to-format-python-dictionary-as-table) for alternate solution. We can also use `as_numpy_iterator()` to get values from tensorflow dataset