# Connecting BatchDataset with Keras VGG16 preprocess_input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` to get a `BatchDataset`, where the dataset has 10 classes.

I am trying to integrate this `BatchDataset` with a Keras `VGG16` ([docs](https://keras.io/api/applications/vgg/)) network.  From the docs:

> Note: each Keras Application expects a specific kind of input preprocessing. For VGG16, call `tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input` on your inputs before passing them to the model.

However, I am struggling to get this `preprocess_input` working with a `BatchDataset`.  **Can you please help me figure out how to connect these two dots?**

Please see the below code:

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(train_data_dir, image_size=(224, 224))
train_ds = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(train_ds)
```

This will throw `TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not subscriptable`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/applications/vgg16.py", line 232, in preprocess_input
    return imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py", line 117, in preprocess_input
    return _preprocess_symbolic_input(
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py", line 278, in _preprocess_symbolic_input
    x = x[..., ::-1]
TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

From [TypeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object is not subscriptable](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39338) (from [BatchDataset not subscriptable when trying to format Python dictionary as table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61642569/11163122)) the suggestion was to use:

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(
    list(train_ds.as_numpy_iterator())
)
```

However, this also fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/applications/vgg16.py", line 232, in preprocess_input
    return imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py", line 117, in preprocess_input
    return _preprocess_symbolic_input(
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py", line 278, in _preprocess_symbolic_input
    x = x[..., ::-1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

This is all using `Python==3.10.3` with `tensorflow==2.8.0`.

How can I get this working?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.  I needed to pass a `tf.Tensor`, not a `tf.data.Dataset`.  One can get a `Tensor` out by iterating over the `Dataset`.

This can be done in a few ways:

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(...)

# Option 1
batch_images = next(iter(train_ds))[0]
preprocessed_images = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(batch_images)

# Option 2:
for batch_images, batch_labels in train_ds:
    preprocessed_images = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(batch_images)
```

If you convert option 2 into a generator, it can be directly passed into the downstream `model.fit`. Cheers!

Comment: But how to convert option 2 into a generator?

Comment: You mean a native Python generator?  You'd append `yield preprocessed_images` inside the `for` loop